# JPanel does not appear in window unless I resize the window

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jpanel

I am new to GUI in java, and have been using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZipG38DJJK8) to learn. When I run the program, the window is blank until I resize it.

```
public class GUIProgram extends JFrame
   {    
   int screenWidth = 1000; //screenSize.width;
   int screenHeight = 800; //screenSize.height;

   public GUIProgram()
      {
      super("DATABASE");

      setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


      JPanel p = new JPanel();
      JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
      JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

      JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton c = new JButton("Button 2");

      p.add(b);
      p.add(c);

          JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Do you LOVE bacon?");
      JCheckBox cb2 = new JCheckBox("Do you LOVE cheese?");

      p2.add(cb);
      p2.add(cb2);

      JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a label");
      JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("this is a test area");
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("text field");

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);

          gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      p3.add(label, gbc);
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 1;
      p3.add(tb, gbc);
      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 2;
      p3.add(textField, gbc);

      add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      }
  }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can lend me some advice!
Please let me know if there is some ambiguity in what I'm asking or how I explained myself.

Comment: You need to pack it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setVisible()` last, immediately after `pack()`.

### Tip:

`setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);`  Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I would +1, but my account is brand new, so I am not allowed for the time being.

Comment: Regarding your tip, does pack make the window as small as it can while keeping everything on the window?

Comment: *"does pack make the window as small as it can while keeping everything on the window?"*  Yes.  Or rather, it does not pack it to the **minimum** size but the **preferred** size of the components inside it.